# Javascript string conversion and array sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I'm attempting a challenge on a JavaScript learning website.

The instructions are:

> It was decided to attribute a "weight" to numbers. The weight of a
>   number will be from now  on the sum of its digits For example 99 will
>   have "weight" 18, 100 will have "weight" 1  so in the list 100 will
>   come before 99. Given a string with the weights of FFC members  in
>   normal order can you give this string ordered by "weights" of these
>   numbers?
>
> Example:
>        a = "56 65 74 100 99 68 86 180 90"ordered by numbers weights  becomes: "100 180 90 56 65 74 68 86 99" When two numbers have the same
>   "weight",  let us class them as if they were strings and not numbers:
>   100 is before 180 because  its "weight" (1) is less than the one of
>   180 (9) and 180 is before 90 since, having the  same "weight" (9) it
>   comes before as a string. All numbers in the list are  positive
>   numbers and the list can be empty.

My attempt is below:

```js
function orderWeight(strng) {

  console.log(strng);
  if (strng === "") {
    return strng;
  } else {
    var arr = strng.split(" ").sort();
    console.log(arr);
    var keys = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var weight = 0;
      var current = arr[i];
      //loop through the array adding the digits of each number
      for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        var sNum = parseInt(arr[i].charAt[j]);
        weight += sNum;
        console.log(weight);
      }
      keys.push({
        weight: weight,
        number: current
      });
      console.log(keys);
    }
  }
};
```

The output from my code is:

```
input string "103 123 4444 99 2000"
console.log(arr); = [ '103', '123', '2000', '4444', '99' ]
console.log(weight); = NaN
```

I realise I will need to do more after I get this portion of code working but if someone could just point me in the direction of getting this part to do what I want I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Just being curious. I gave it a try, is this correct? http://jsfiddle.net/umdg3h9z/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using brackets instead of parentheses when calling `charAt`.

Change this:

```
var sNum = parseInt(arr[i].charAt[j]);
```

to:

```
var sNum = parseInt(arr[i].charAt(j));
```

Answer (score 2):

Compute the weight of each string by converting it to an integer and taking the sum of the digits:

```
var weight = 0,
    x = parseInt(parts[i], 10);
while (x != 0) {
  var digit = x % 10;
  weight += digit;
  x = (x - digit) / 10;
}
```

Then make objects that contain each value and the string it came from:

```
sorted[i] = { weight: weight, string: parts[i] };
```

Now you can [sort the objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a comparison function that uses the weights if they differ, and the [standard string comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) otherwise:

```
sorted.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.weight != b.weight) {
    return a.weight - b.weight;
  }
  return a.string.localeCompare(b.string);
});
```

Finally, extract the strings and print them to show the result.

Demonstration:

```js
function print(s) {
  document.write(s + '<br />');
}

function solve(s) {
  print('input: ' + s);
  var parts = s.split(' '),
      n = parts.length,
      sorted = new Array(n);
  for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    var weight = 0,
        x = parseInt(parts[i], 10);
    while (x != 0) {
      var digit = x % 10;
      weight += digit;
      x = (x - digit) / 10;
    }
    sorted[i] = { weight: weight, string: parts[i] };
  }
  sorted.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.weight != b.weight) {
      return a.weight - b.weight;
    }
    return a.string.localeCompare(b.string);
  });
  var newParts = new Array(n);
  for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    newParts[i] = sorted[i].string;
  }
  print('output: ' + newParts.join(' '));
}

solve("56 65 74 100 99 68 86 180 90");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a function to calculate the weights then use a [custom sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort your array.

Here's a running example.

```js
var input = "56 65 74 100 99 68 86 180 90";
var a = input.split(" ");
a.sort(function(x, y) {
  var xWeight = getWeight(x);
  var yWeight = getWeight(y);
  if (xWeight === yWeight)
    return x > y;
  else
    return xWeight > yWeight;
});

function getWeight(x) {
  var weight = 0;
  var arr = x.split("");
  arr.forEach(function(i) {
    weight += parseInt(i, 10);
  });
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follow:

```
function getWeight(string){
  return eval(string.split('').join('+'))
}

function orderWeight(string){
  return string.split(' ').sort(function(a,b){
    var wA = getWeight(a), wB = getWeight(b);
    if(wA>wB) return 1;
    if(wA<wB) return -1;
    if(a>b)   return 1;
    if(a<b)   return -1;
    return 0;
  }).join(' ');
}
```